# boost python library linking issue -- undefined symbol

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ubuntu, boost

I am using boost-python built for python3 to expose a simple hello-world program. The example can be found here : https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/blob/master/01-HelloWorld/hello.cpp

I ran the following commands to get the shared object:

```
g++ -fPIC -c -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/python3.4m  -Wno-unused-result -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34 hello.cpp

g++ -shared hello.o -o hello.so
```

After this, I run the `python3 -c 'import hello'` command and I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: hello.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseE

I partly understand this issue may be because my boost-python installation may be built for an alternative python version (for instance python2.7). When I run the command:

`ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python*.so`

There are three .so files:

```
1. libboost_python-py27.so
2. libboost_python-py34.so
3. libboost_python.so
```

How can this issue be circumvented?

Comment: instead of 'g++ -shared hello.o -o hello.so' you can try to add the full qualifier, with -L and -I. I was having the same problem and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

use pkg-config to retrieve ldflags and cflags of your boost library

Comment: `pkg-config libboost --lib` gives me the output `No package 'libboost' found`

Comment: which distribution are you using ? there was something wrong with your cmd line -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34 is not right it should be the directory /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and -lboost-py34

Comment: Using ubuntu:14.04

Comment: I recompiled with this command to get the same result:`g++ -fPIC -c -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/python3.4m  -Wno-unused-result -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -libboost_python-py34 hello.cpp`

Comment: this should be pkg-config libboost-python-dev --libs

Comment: Same output as earlier. It says that the `Package libboost-python-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path`.

Comment: unfortunately there does not seem to have a pkg-config for it in this distribution . (https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libboost-python1.54-dev/filelist) . so, we will try to find the right cmdline. And you missed -lboost_python or -lboost_python34 in the cmdline and -lpython

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151444/discussion-between-envy-intelligence-and-sancelot).

Answer (score 0):

Installing miniconda might be an option for you.  https://conda.io/miniconda.html

This will provide a complete, isolated, python environment.  You can then 
`conda install boost`

I've tested this on my system and it worked well.  I modified the Makefile from http://www.shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/linking-python-and-c-with-boostpython/

My Makefile can be found here:
https://github.com/grelleum/boost-python-with-anaconda

Comment: Link https://github.com/grelleum/boost-python-with-anaconda does not exist anymore